# How can I create a task automatically by creating a new workitem in TFS?

Tags: tfs, workitem

I would like to know can I create a new linked task when I create a workitem.

Can anyone give a tip of how to do this?

Comment: Are you using VSO or TFS? If TFS, you can create what's called a server plugin. Or you use the service hooks to be notified when a work item is created and then create a new task.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I'm using TFS...To create a server plugin do you have any link that I can use as a guide? In my company they ask me to make this process automated so server plugin is the best option for me.

Answer (score 5):

I've gone through some old code that I previously used for this scenario. The following code creates a linked task whenever a new bug is set to approved.

The code filters to a specific Team Project and uses a specific account to connect. You need to enter these before the plugin will work. You can then modify this code to create the tasks you want.

For a general introduction to server plugins and how to turn the code below into a functioning plugin see [Extending Team Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx)

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;

namespace TfsExtension.CreateTaskForBug
{
    public class CreateTaskForBugEventHandler : ISubscriber
    {
        const string projectName = "<Enter your project name here>";

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "CreateTaskForBugEventHandler";
            }
        }

        public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get
            {
                return SubscriberPriority.Normal;
            }
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
            TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext,
            NotificationType notificationType,
            object notificationEventArgs,
            out int statusCode,
            out string statusMessage,
            out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                ProcessNotification(notificationType, notificationEventArgs, requestContext);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                TeamFoundationApplicationCore.LogException("Error processing event", exception);
            }
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;

        }

        private static void ProcessNotification(NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
            {
                var ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;

                if (ev.PortfolioProject == projectName)
                {
                    string workItemType = (from field in ev.CoreFields.StringFields
                                           where field.Name == "Work Item Type"
                                           select field.NewValue).Single();

                    if (workItemType == "Bug")
                    {
                        ProcessBug(ev, requestContext);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ProcessBug(WorkItemChangedEvent ev, TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
        {
            var stateChange = (from field in ev.ChangedFields.StringFields
                               where field.Name == "State" && field.NewValue == "Approved"
                               select field).SingleOrDefault();

            if (stateChange != null)
            {
                AddChildTaskToBug(ev, requestContext);
            }
        }

        private static void AddChildTaskToBug(WorkItemChangedEvent ev, TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
        {
            WorkItemStore wiStore = GetWorkItemStore(requestContext);
            WorkItem witem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(ev.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0].NewValue);

            Project teamProject = witem.Project;
            int bugID = witem.Id;

            string bugTitle = witem.Fields["System.Title"].Value.ToString();
            string bugAssignedTo = witem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value.ToString();
            string bugAreaPath = witem.Fields["System.AreaPath"].Value.ToString();
            string bugIterationPath = witem.Fields["System.IterationPath"].Value.ToString();
            string bugChangedBy = witem.Fields["System.ChangedBy"].OriginalValue.ToString();
            string bugTeamProject = witem.Project.Name;

            string childTaskTitle = "Resolve bug " + bugID + " - " + bugTitle;

            if (CreateResolutionTask(wiStore, bugID, childTaskTitle))
            {
                witem = CreateWorkItem(wiStore, teamProject, bugID, bugTitle, bugAssignedTo, bugAreaPath, bugIterationPath);

                if (IsValid(witem))
                {
                    witem.Save();

                    LinkParentAndChild(wiStore, witem, bugID);
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool IsValid(WorkItem witem)
        {
            ArrayList validationErrors = witem.Validate();
            return validationErrors.Count == 0;
        }

        private static void LinkParentAndChild(WorkItemStore wiStore, WorkItem witem, int bugID)
        {
            var linkType = wiStore.WorkItemLinkTypes[CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames.Hierarchy];

            var parentWorkItem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(bugID);
            int taskID = witem.Id;
            var childWorkItem = wiStore.GetWorkItem(taskID);

            parentWorkItem.Links.Add(new WorkItemLink(linkType.ForwardEnd, childWorkItem.Id));
            parentWorkItem.Save();
        }

        private static WorkItem CreateWorkItem(WorkItemStore wiStore, Project teamProject, int bugID, string bugTitle, string bugAssignedTo, string bugAreaPath, string bugIterationPath)
        {
            WorkItemTypeCollection workItemTypes = wiStore.Projects[teamProject.Name].WorkItemTypes;
            WorkItemType wiType = workItemTypes["Task"];

            WorkItem witem = new WorkItem(wiType);
            witem.Fields["System.Title"].Value = "Resolve bug " + bugID + " - " + bugTitle;
            witem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value = bugAssignedTo;
            witem.Fields["System.AreaPath"].Value = bugAreaPath;
            witem.Fields["System.IterationPath"].Value = bugIterationPath;
            witem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity"].Value = "Bug Resolution";
            return witem;
        }

        private static bool CreateResolutionTask(WorkItemStore wiStore, int bugID, string childTaskTitle)
        {
            WorkItem parentBug = wiStore.GetWorkItem(bugID);
            WorkItemLinkCollection links = parentBug.WorkItemLinks;
            foreach (WorkItemLink wil in links)
            {
                if (wil.LinkTypeEnd.Name == "Child")
                {
                    WorkItem childTask = wiStore.GetWorkItem(wil.TargetId);

                    if ((childTask.Title == childTaskTitle) && (childTask.State != "Closed"))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static Uri GetTFSUri(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
        {
            var locationService = requestContext.GetService<TeamFoundationLocationService>();
            return new Uri(locationService.GetServerAccessMapping(requestContext).AccessPoint + "/" + requestContext.ServiceHost.Name);
        }

        private static WorkItemStore GetWorkItemStore(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
        {
            NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(
                   "<username>",
                   "<password>");

            WindowsCredential windowsCred = new WindowsCredential(netCred);
            var credentials = new TfsClientCredentials(windowsCred);
            credentials.AllowInteractive = true;

            var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                GetTFSUri(requestContext),
                credentials);

            tpc.Authenticate();

            return tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        }

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[1] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };
        }
    }
}
```